# Synchronous state provider?

Tags: extjs4

I'm creating a TabPanel component where the specific tabs are created/defined by user configuration.

So far, I've taken the approach of just using a stateful component to keep the users preferences of which tabs to show and been using the simple `Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider` to keep the users preferences.

But I actually ultimately want to store the user preferences/config in my database, so I created my own `StateProvider` that will store/load the prefs via AJAX calls.

The problem I've encountered is that my tab panel is loaded far sooner than the AJAX calls inside my StateProvider return, so what I need is some way to do a synchronous ajax call (which I know is morally wrong) or to somehow delay my tab panel from rendering until the preferences in my state provider are finished loading.

Anyone had a similar issue?  It might be as simple as sleeping one thread for a while, but I know that's not nice either.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit old, but as I have found a similar problem...

Instead of sleeping, you can load the tab panel on the listener of your StateProvider ajax calls. So when your call returns, the tab will still not be loaded.